# Firebase performance monitoring does not show session details

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-performance

I have added performance monitoring to iOS project.
The automatic traces as well as custom traces appear in the dashboard. Also the aggregated network calls are visible in network tab. 
But I am not able to see details of trace samples. If I click 'see sessions' a message saying to update the Firebase Sdk is displayed.

I am using Firebase SDK 5.13.0, which is the latest stable SDK.

Comment: Did you update the SDK as it suggested?  Are you using a version of the SDK that supports session samples?

Comment: I updated the pod file  (pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.13.0',
    pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.13.0')  and did pod install. The sessions samples were introduced in version 5.11.0. So, 5.13.0 should support it.

Comment: But still the session details are not visible.

Comment: Same here. Have you found a solution to the problem?

Comment: Same here, have you found a solution ? @TalL

Comment: Yes. Apprently all you need is patience. After a while and enough sessions, the information becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that Performance Monitoring data usually displays within 12 hours of testing your app.

Unfortunately, based on their [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios#data-in-console) docs, they mentioned that the data takes up to 12 hours to be displayed. So, we will just have to wait for it to appear.